# Using basic http authentication to authorize connection

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, authentication, httprequest

I am trying to make a login to an external salesforce org from my salesforce org. Below is the code using basic authentication but I get an error:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://xxx.cs30.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/39.0');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/text'); 
// Because we didn't set the endpoint as a named credential, 
// our code has to specify:
// - The required username and password to access the endpoint
// - The header and header information

String username = 'username@test.com';
String password = 'passwordddd';

Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +
EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

// Create a new http object to send the request object
// A response object is generated as a result of the request  

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

I get an error back:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
>     <soapenv:Body>
>         <soapenv:Fault>
>             <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
>             <faultstring>content-type of the request should be text/xml</faultstring>
>         </soapenv:Fault>
>     </soapenv:Body>
> </soapenv:Envelope>
> ```

I made the content type as 'application/xml' or 'application/text' but doesn't seem to work. I am guessing I am not doing this in the right way to authorize the endpoint.

Comment: The error message seems quite clear, no? Change the `content-type` to `text/xml`.

Comment: I made the change but I get an error now - POST requires content-length. I think I have to setBody for this but I have a JSON body. I am trying to hit an apex rest service present in another salesforce org. How do I make modification to code to hit that service endpoint? Any Idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use Basic Authentication with Salesforce. Instead, use the [SOAP login()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm) call or the [OAuth Username-Password](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm) authentication flow.

Comment: Even using username-Password authentication flow, we need to define the calling org as connected app in the target org right(to get customer token)?

Comment: @javanoob If you use username-password auth flow, you simply need a client ID of a connected app. It does not need to already exist in the target org. Or, you can use SOAP login, which does not require a connected app.

Comment: Ok. I was under the impression that we should have the connected app defined in the target org. I just did some testing using the client and customer secret of a totally different app(defined in a 3rd org) and I am able to get access token(This might be a bad practice to use client id and customer secret of different app). Learnt new thing today. Thanks again!

Comment: @javanoob Yes, definitely use your own connected app for this purpose.

Comment: @sfdcfox My main goal here is I should not store username and password(specially password) that is visbile to other user. Like If I use SOAP login() I have to store the credentials in a custom setting which can be viewed by other users. I want something like Named credential which hides the password. What do you suggest here? Does OAuth will solve my case here?

Comment: @SfdcBat You can use a Named Credential to connect to the other org via OAuth.

Comment: Thank you! Would setting up Oauth requires the external salesforce org to make any confiuration changes?( Example creating a connected app in the other salesforce org or can it be handle without involving the external org). My point of integration is a button click on a record.

Comment: @SfdcBat The connected app can exist in either org (or even a third org). Once a login is established, no further authentication is necessary, because the system handles refresh tokens for you automatically.